# how i can add order summary section on the payment page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkout-page

I want to replace order summary section in place of Estimated total section in the mobile view. but it should be same in desktop view as default , should change only on mobile view.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to override grand-total.html to theme file.

located at :

app\design\Theme\Theme_Name\Magento_Tax\view\frontend\web\template\checkout\summary.

Comment: can is do this only css or js??

Comment: Do check with html and check.